# AWS SQS : How do I know that I am processing the last message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

[image]

```
  massPayoutExecute:
    handler: lambda/execute.php
    timeout: 120 # 2 minutes
    layers:
      - arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:<ACCOUNT::ID>:layer:php-81:1
    reservedConcurrency: 10
    role: MyRole
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn: !GetAtt MyQueue.Arn
          batchSize: 1
          maximumBatchingWindow: 60

...

    MyQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: ${opt:stage}-${opt:client}-MyQueue
        VisibilityTimeout: 900
        DelaySeconds: 300
```

For example, for 500 messages, I have these objects:

```
1 Object Parent:
{
    "id": 123,
    "iteration": 0,
    "numberOfChild": 500
}

500 Object Child:
{
    "parentId": 123,
    "treated": false
}
```

- The Lambda 01 stores perfectly the object `Parent` and the 500
  objects `Child` and, sets `Parent::numberOfChild` to 500.
- The Lambda 01 can send an indefinite number of messages (can send 10k
  for example).
- The SQS queue receives all the messages and sends them to Lambda 02
  (no error here).
- For each message, Lambda 02 updates an entry for `Child::treated` and
  `Parent::iteration` in DynamoDB.
- When the `Parent` object is new, `Parent::iteration` equals 0 and the
  Lambda 02 must increment this number for each message it receives.

**My issue:**

Lambda 02 manages to update all the `Child` objects perfectly but does not manage to update the incrementation of `Parent::iteration` correctly.

In my code, I compare the value of `Parent::iteration` with `Parent::numberOfChild` to continue a new process.

If Lambda 02 has a `reservedConcurrency = 1`, it works perfectly (I reach the point where `Parent::iteration` equals `Parent::numberOfChild`) but, if `reservedConcurrency = 10`, `Parent::iteration` doesn't update correctly and I never have `Parent::iteration` equals `Parent::numberOfChild`.

I definitely want to keep the concurrency at 10.

**My question:**

Do you have any idea how I can know when Lambda 02 processes the last message received by SQS, please?

I don't want to use a FIFO SQS.

Comment: SQS cannot help you here, using FIFO would basically result in a concurrency of 1 as well in your case. Rather this is purely a DynamoDB question: how do you currently update the counter value, how do you check whether the two numbers are equal?

Comment: Thank's for your response @luk2302 . On PHP (Laravel), I just get the current Parent::iteration in DynamoDB (when Parent was created, iteration = 0) and, I simply add +1 and I update Parent in DynamoDB.

The problem with currency > 1: The Lambda's can get the same value for Parent::iteration

Comment: Your lambda needs to send an update to the dynamodb, it literally needs to send a + 1, your lambda must not retrieve the value first, add one and then save that value. As a response to that + 1 the lambda should get the updated value back from dynamo and can then check if the value is now 500. Generally speaking something like this is better done using e.g. StepFunctions.

Comment: How I can add +1 on the Parent::iteration value if I don't get it before?

Comment: Basically by sending an `Update` with either `SET iteration = iteration + 1` or `ADD iteration 1` (the syntax depends on your language).

Comment: The feature luk2302 is describing is called Atomic Counters. It is documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters

Comment: @luk2302 You are right, I tried to use FIFO and the result is the same as a classic queue with a lambda in concurency 1. Except if I change the value of messageGroupId every x iterations. In this case I get my messages in disorder and I don't want that. In FIFO if the messages belong to the same messageGroupId, only one lambda is executed.

Comment: @MarkB Thank's I didn't know this feature. I'll try.

Comment: All working good with Atomic Counters, thanks both :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @luk2302 and @mark-b , it's working when I use Atomic Counters https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters to update `Parent::iteration`